# When storing chinese word in MySQL, it becomes scrambled code

Tags: python, mysql, django

I use Python/Django to connet to MySQL.

When I store a Chinese string in Mysql, I get scrambled codes.
What happened?

I have set `settings.py` of my Django project, and the `ENCODING` key is set to `utf-8`. What did I do wrong?

This is my `DATABASES` variable in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'NAME': 'admindb1',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'ENCODING': 'utf-8',
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the value? Are you sure it isn't the binary string representation?

Comment: show the mysql setting in  settings.py

Comment: Just curious ... Is that a right way to give ENCODING ? Where you refer ?

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: Do you use Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @Pyfisch python 2.7.X

Comment: @tony yang are you using u"Unicode strings"? you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know why I can't store Chinese word.

When I entered mysql console, I typed `status` to inspect my mysql configure. I found server and db characterset wasn't utf8 that caused scrambled code of reason.

This is my solution. I used vim to edit `my.cnf`. My linux machine is Debian, so the cnf directory locate `etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

It added is like below and stored the content:

```
[mysqld] 
character-set-server=utf8 
collation-server=utf8_general_ci 
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8' 
[client] 
default-character-set=utf8
```

When I created a new db, its configure can store utf8.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware of the character-set/collation settings at the database/table/column levels. Column-level settings take precedence over the others. Because of this, I'm including commands you can use to perform these changes at each level of the db.

---

Inspect your current configuration (database):

SHOW CREATE DATABASE db_name;

Inspect your current configuration (table):

SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name='tbl_name'

Inspect your current configuration (columns):

SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tbl_name;

---

Change the character-set/collation (database):

ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;

Change the character-set/collation (table):

ALTER TABLE tbl_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;

Change the character-set/collation (columns):

ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;